# How to find all Elements of a specific Type with the new Requests-HTML library

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping, python-requests-html

I wanna find all specific fields in a HTML, in Beautiful soup everything is working with this code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'html.parser')
urls_previous = soup.find_all('h2', {'class': 'b_algo'})
```

but how can I make the same search with the requests library or can requests only find a single element in a HTML document, I couldn't find how to do it in the docs or examples ?

https://html.python-requests.org/

Example:

```html
<li class="b_algo"><h2><a href="https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vereinigte_Staaten">Vereinigte Staaten – Wikipedia</a></h2><a href="https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vereinigte_Staaten">https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vereinigte_Staaten</a></div><p>U.S., I wanna have THIS text here</p></li>
```

How can I find all Elements of a specific type with the requests library ?

Comment: To be clear, `requests-html` is a different package then `requests`. In `requests-html` you can use CSS selectors or Xpaths to select certain elements. If you need help selecting a particular element in your `html_text`, please include it in your question as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with [requests-html](http://html.python-requests.org/)

```
from requests_html import HTML
doc = """<li class="b_algo"><h2><a href="https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vereinigte_Staaten">Vereinigte Staaten – Wikipedia</a></h2><a href="https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vereinigte_Staaten">https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vereinigte_Staaten</a></div><p>U.S., I wanna have THIS text here</p></li>"""
#load html from string
html = HTML(html=doc)
x = html.find('h2')
print(x)
```